# Unexpected Syntax Error PHP for use Extended variables into child class

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-8

I searched on PHP manual and W3Schools, the exactly syntax for the bellow PHP Code, I'm working on Netbeans.

The code use an Array Variables that it has immplemented in to a super class
 `(es UPDATE_LISTINI["TABLE_NAME"] => "table_name").`

The super Class has extended in the current class. All Works correctly, but netbeans show me this code as a syntax error

```
switch ($tablename){ 
    case self::UPDATE_LISTINI["TABLE_NAME"] : 
      return self::SELECT."MAX(".$fields.") ".self::FROM.self::UPDATE_LISTINI["TABLE_NAME"]; 
    case self::UPDATE_PROMO["TABLE_NAME"] : 
      return self::SELECT."MAX(".$fields.") ".self::FROM.self::UPDATE_PROMO["TABLE_NAME"]; 
    case self::UPDATE_SCONTI["TABLE_NAME"] : 
      return self::SELECT."MAX(".$fields.") ".self::FROM.self::UPDATE_SCONTI["TABLE_NAME"];  
}
```

Could someone post me some web manual where i can get more details about the correctly php syntax use please?

Thanks

Comment: Web manual for php syntax? Let's see.. I don't know, maybe [php.net](http://php.net)?

Answer (score 0):

Question is incomplete could not digest it enough. Still I would suggest....

Some times IDE Editors show errors which are just for them not for compilers. Try to run the code and paste here what exact error is displayed on web browser(not in editor).